# Engine not rev over 3500 after new ECU installed same number

Tags: civic, rough-idle, rpm, electronic-control-module

I have Honda civic vtec 1999 with D15 engine installed.

ECU/PCM reporting error and mechanic told me this computing having issue in IC

I bought new ECU same number but after connecting, car engine starts and work fine, but when you press gas pedal RPM never go up from 3500

What should I do?

Note:
I have already unplugin and plugin battery.

Comment: This sounds like you need to connect it to a full level diagnostic computer so the ecu recognizes the engine.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: After complete level diagnose, following error showing in scan tool - but no engine light on.
P0335 - CPK Sensor No Signal
-- Possible Failure
---- Signal line open
---- Signal like short
---- Ground line open
---- Sensor failure
--------
After connecting new sensor check engine light comes.
--------
Sensor Part number should be matched or just same size and style can be used?

Comment: I have disconnect and reconnect battery for reset ECU but still engine light.
-- should I need to remove code from scanner?
-- should the part number must matched?